# Is it safe to remove water damaged OSB and drywall from interior walls?

Tags: drywall, walls, interior, frame

We have just recently taken over a old house, used previously as a bed and breakfast, and noticed water damage on the bottom of all the walls.

I started sawing away at the drywall quickly to find OSB behind it.

I am wondering if it is safe to start removing the OSB on the interior walls. As of now, I see no other way as the OSB and the drywall has been rotted and molded due to the water damage.

Photo 1 is the general look of the interior wall. Photo 2 is the bottom wood frame. Underneath seems to be concrete and the OSB goes deep into the floor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the statement that "OSB board does deep into the floor"?

Comment: It seems that the osb board goes deep into the floor as there is a raised floor right next to it. We are assuming it is because of the floor heat pipes and they covered it with cement. But also, the entire floor looks like its layerd with cement as well 

It's a wood house with wood frames, metal roof trusses and cement layered floors.

Comment: The use of OSB under drywall is unusual.  Is this a basement?  If this were water damage, do you have any idea where it came from?

Comment: I found it a bit odd myself. The internet tells me its either an interior shear wall or just for sound control, insulation, etc., which does make sense since this house is divided into 6 individual seperate rooms to serve as bed and breakfast. 

The water damage came from the room right on the other side of this wall, which has a sink that the pipes burst.

Comment: So is this actually water damage or is it just staining?  OSB generally is water tolerant for short exposures and there doesn't appear to be any swelling of it in the photos.  Is the bottom plate compromised?  If this is a one-time short-term exposure I don't think there is anything you need to do here.  If there is mold and/or rot, you are not showing that in the photos.

Comment: @Diynewbie -- are you in an area that has significant earthquake or wind hazards?

Comment: There was water damage of about a hands length and mold on the drywall. We took the part of osb and drywall out that was affected. The osb kind of just fell apart when poking it. 

Decided to cut the osb a quarter length of the whole wall from the floor. But stopped due to fears that the osb board serves more purpose than interior functions.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Nope. Just on the coastlines of south korea. No crazy wind and no earthquake hazards.

Comment: @Diynewbie ...no typhoons?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel There are some on rare occasions. One every few years but other than that there are no typhoons on a normal basis.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that this is a shear wall, or that the wall wasn't originally finished with drywall and required at least *some* diagonal bracing because it's load-bearing.  For that reason I wouldn't completely strip it, but you should be fine doing as you are and removing the bottom 16" or whatever. You may be required (or wise) to float blocking behind those seams then, in order to restore solid diagonal connection.

Your best bet may be to get your local inspection authority involved. They'll offer advice regarding requirements and possibly best practices.

Comment: Especially since OP is in S. Korea and most of "our" collective expertise seems to be from N. America, Europe and some Australia.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will definately call around to try to get an inspection authority involved. 

Would you think that if we re-nail the osb board on the parts we cut out, the structrual integrity will still stay the same? Or should we put the blocking up before hand?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Obviously you have to re-nail the OSB, and obviously you have to put blocking in first. What am I missing?